# node istanbul code coverage with Jasmine producing an empty coverage folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, istanbul

I am running jasmine to test my code and it works fine.

In my package.json file I have this command:

"cover": "./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover node_modules/.bin/jasmine-node unit_test"

where unit_test contains my jasmine spec.

For some reason when I run my coverage it runs my jasmine tests, produces an empty coverage folder and then hangs.

Does anyone know why please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt anyone will ever read this but I found a solution if youre facing the same problem.

Ensure your db connection is closing - istanbul will just hang forever and wait for all connections to close before doing anything.